# Как узнать почему меняется таблица маршрутизации Linux

Tags: linux, centos, маршрутизация

Подключил к серверу (centos7) Yota через USB как резервный канал связи. В первые секунды всё ок, маршрут определяется правильно. Через несколько секунд маршрут по умолчанию из таблицы маршрутизации пропадает.

При задании маршрута статически в конфиге и/или вручную через ip route ситуация повторяется. 
Адреса/маршруты на остальных картах прописаны статически.

Как узнать почему меняется таблица маршрутизации?

Comment: [oracle mode on]network manager[oracle mode off].

Comment: network manager выключать пробовал, проблема сохраняется

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, список процессов (`$ ps aux`). возможно, это поможет определить «виновника». надеюсь, cron-задания **всех** пользователей вы уже проинспектировали (`/var/spool/cron/crontabs/*`).

Comment: Данная проблема ушла сама сабой - через несколько часов маршрут назначился нормально и больше не слетал.

По крон-задачам да, смотрел. В целом там всё настраивается вручную, пользователей особо нет - это сервер для резервных копий + пара докер-контейнеров запущена. Так что возможно меняет докер, но слабо похоже (с обычными подключениями не слетает).

Так что остался сам вопрос - можно ли как-то узнать процесс, который таблицу маршрутизации меняет (не угадать по знакомому названию, а именно узнать кто меняет).

Comment: насколько я знаю — нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

команда

```
ip monitor
```

по ней в реальном времени выводятся все изменения с IP-адресами, маршрутизацией и т.п.

В данном конкретном случае я увидел, что маршрут по-умолчанию удаляется каждый раз при попытке создать ppp-соединение (основной способ подключения к интернет) и потом восстанавливается снова.

Answer (score 1):

Если запретить менять таблицу маршрутизации для всех процессов через SELinux, то виновник будет виден в audit.log

Comment: В целом это может быть решением. Я с SELinux знаком очень отдалённо. Как можно запретить изменять таблицу маршрутизации и как потом в аудите найти этот процесс.

Может быть можно не запретить совсем, а поставить событие на аудит - т.е. чтобы просто запись происходила?